# ¿Como hacer una Select y un Update en un solo comando con pdo?

Tags: php, mysql

Necesito recuperar e incrementar un contador, que no es un id autoincremental en una tabla, y evitar errores de concurrencia. No quiero hacer bloqueos de tabla por su elevado coste en recursos.

He estado viendo este artículo (http://www.sqlines.com/mysql/how-to/select-update-single-statement-race-condition) y he probado la parte que dice "Select and Update in Single Statement" y me funciona perfecto en MariaDB.

He estado probando de implementarlo con PDO y no lo logro.

Esta es mi función:

```
$dbConnection = new \PDO('mysql:host='.$host.';dbname='.$dbal_dbname.';charset=utf8', $dbal_user, $dbal_password, [\PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true, \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);    
$stmt = $this->dbConnection->prepare('UPDATE config SET config_value = (@cur_value := config_value) + 1 WHERE config_name = "proximo_asiento"');
$stmt->execute();
$stmt = $this->dbConnection->prepare('SELECT @cur_value;');
$returned_field = $stmt->execute();

/* Tambien he probado sustitutendo la ultima linea con: */

$stmt->execute();
$returned_field = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

El contador de la tabla, es decir el campo config_value correspondiente al config_name de "proximo_asiento" se incrementa bien pero el resultado, el returned_field, siempre es 1 aunque el campo "proximo_asiento sea 235".

La conexion, los comandos PDO,... estan comprobados.

Creo que el problema esta en como recupero la última SQL. Pero no logro encontrar donde está mal.

Una ayudita.... gracias.

Comment: Lo encontré.... $returned field es un array... menuda....

Comment: ¿ Qué quieres decir con: *No quiero hacer bloqueos de tabla por su elevado coste en recursos.*  ? Me parece muy extraño y peligroso tu código, sobre todo si va a funcionar en un entorno con conexiones concurrentes (varios usuarios al mismo tiempo modificando datos). Quizá convendría usar transacciones...

Comment: ¿Porque peligroso?¿Porque extraño?. Transacciones es equivalente a bloqueo, ¿no es cierto?. Debo advertir de que el código no usa ningun dato que necesite ser sanitizado. Si bloqueo una tabla hay un consumo de recursos. El resto de usuarios debe esperar al desbloqueo, otro consumo de recursos. Estoy haciendo un update y me guardo el número anterior al update en una variable en la misma transacción SQL. ¿Crees que MariaDB podría devolver a dos usuarios diferentes el mismo número?.

Comment: En conexiones concurrentes todo es posible,  al ver tu código uno tiene la impresión de que estás intentando *reinventar la rueda*. Peligroso porque con ese código en cualquier momento te puede devolver un valor que no es el correcto y meter un gran lío en los datos. Creo que estás subestimando la capacidad del manejador de base de datos y en consecuencia creando una especie de código que sustituye funciones que el manejador hace muchísimo mejor, con mucha más seguridad y eficacia.

Comment: He estado viendo algunas intervenciones tuyas en SOes y parece que tienes un conocimiento profundo de Bases de Datos. Respeto tu respuesta pero no veo argumentación alguna y la hecho en falta. Podrías indicar porque consideras que en mi caso concreto estoy reinventando la rueda. Asi mismo podrías indicar en que caso concreto podría obtener un valor ya otorgado si solo estoy ejecutando una consulta UPDATE. ¿Puede un manejador de bases de datos devolver un valor distinto después de un UPDATE?. No tengo ningún animo de ofender, solo de aprender. He leido mucho sobre bloqueos y busco alternativas.

Comment: Recomendaría que leas sobre las transacciones y para qué sirven. Digo que estás reinventando la rueda porque las transacciones se ocupan precisamente de eso. La cuestión aquí no es el manejador, él hace lo que le digas si organizas bien tu código. Piensa en un escenario como este: cierto campo tiene el valor `1` cuando tú lo recuperas y lo usas para otra cosa. ¿Qué tal si en ese proceso otro usuario lo actualiza a `7`? Vas a trabajar pensando que el campo vale `1` y todo lo que hagas en ese intervalo será erróneo. Ese tipo de cosas pasan en conexiones concurrentes...

Comment: ... y el manejador de bases de datos tiene formas de escribir las consultas para tratar ese tipo de situaciones. Además partes de una premisa que no es cierta, los bloqueos de tabla (en el contexto de transacciones) no tienen un alto costo como dices. Las cosas existen por algo y están optimizadas para funcionar de la mejor forma posible. Este es mi punto de vista, no quiero que me des la razón , solo planteo otro punto de vista a tu problema. Te toca a ti ensayar lo que te convienen, será la experiencia la que dirá si era o no el mejor camino.

Comment: Insisto, sin animo de ofender, no me das ninguna razón para estar obligado a usar transacciones en mi escenario. He entendido perfectamente lo que son conexiones concurrentes. He estado también ampliando conocimientos acerca de las "Race conditions", que aunque no es exactamente mi caso se parece.  He leido bastante sobre el coste de los bloqueos.En algunos casos es mejor usarlos y en otras ocasiones se pueden utilizar otras técnicas.

Comment: Estoy casi de acuerdo de que las cosas existen por alguna razón, sin embargo no siempre están exactamente para lo que nos imaginamos. Disculpa si lo pregunto una vez más: ¿Puede un manejador de bases de datos devolver un valor distinto después de un UPDATE?.

Comment: Ya te respondí: sí puede (inversamente),  si otro usuario lo actualiza inmediatamente después el valor ya es *distinto* y tú estarás trabajando sobre datos que no reflejan la realidad. (El ejemplo del `1` y el `7` en uno de mis anteriores comentarios).

Comment: Pero se trata de un contador: "proximo_asiento". Si un usuario lo actualiza despues de que se haya cambiado cojerá el siguiente valor del contador y lo actualizará, y así sucesivamente. Con el código que estamos evaluando no hay un espacio de tiempo ni de proceso entre la lectura y la actualización, es solo una sentencia. Las transacciones evitan que un segundo proceso se "cuele" entre la lectura y la actualización y que por ello lo leido deje de ser realidad. Pero cuando es una sola sentencia eso no puede pasar, ¿verdad?. Esta es mi duda y lo que realmente estoy preguntando.

Comment: Que malas son las dudas. Ante la falta de argumentos organizé un test con un millón de consultas concurrentes y en ninguno de los varios casos que planteé el código que no ocupa falló. Puedo decir que es seguro para ciertos casos. Dejo este comentario por si alguién tiene mi misma duda y se confunde con los comentarios posteriores a mi consulta.